# jQuery script not recognised when injected in my view (.cshtml)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Usually I create a javascript file (myfile.js) for my scripts.

Example:

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/Jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {

    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function             
    $('#uploadBackgroundForm').ajaxForm({
        iframe: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: BackgroundUploadedSuccess,
        error: BackgroundUploadedError
    });

});
```

Now I would like to place my script directly in my view (.cshtml) in a section (< script type="text/javascript">.....< / script >).

Example:

```
...my view goes here...

<script type="text/javascript">
    /// <reference path="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" />

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function             
        $('#uploadBackgroundForm').ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: BackgroundUploadedSuccess,
            error: BackgroundUploadedError
        });
});
....
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. I mean when I place my cursor on a jQuery syntax like 'ready' and click CTRL+J nothing is recognised.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the reference with such construct :

```
@if (false)
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

With the `@if (false)` the script is not loaded at runtime... (You can also see this [page](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/javascript-intellisense-in-razor-jscript-files-in-visual-studio-2010/)).

UPDATE :
You have to insert this code just before your other script tag.

Answer (score 2):

By your mention of `clicking CTRL+J` I assume you mean you're trying to get Visual Studio to list the members of a jQuery object? If so, by default VS does not do this.

However, it is possible to add this in to VS2008 by following the instructions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx) from Scott Guthrie about adding a `vsdoc` for jQuery.

At present, the most up to date `vsdoc` on the jQuery site is for 1.4.1 ([here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js)), however you may be able to find a more up to date non-official version by googling.

Comment: @Samuel thanks but in fact adding the line /// < reference path="../../Scripts/Jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" / > will also do the trick. At least in my .js files. Unfortunately I didn't succeed having the same behaviour in my .cshtml files

Comment: @Bronzato : your comment should have been placed under my text :-) But my solution (with the `@if (false)` is provided to replace the `/// reference path`syntax in a .cshtml file. I have already use this and it works well.